# C Programming: How to write char after malloc?

Tags: c

I am learning to use pointers in C and I am testing how to write a char after malloc ?  Below is my code, but it's not working. I'm looking for some help here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZECHAR 10   // write 10 char starting from the first position of malloc

int main(void)
{
//      char *charArray = (char *)malloc(SIZECHAR * sizeof(char));

        char *charArray = "helloworld";   // this is a temporary pointer

        while (*charArray != '\0')
        {
                int *currentIndex = (int *) charArray++;
                printf("the current pointer is %i\n", *currentIndex);  // print out the current pointer
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. The subject asks about doing something "after malloc", but the line of code with the call to `malloc()` has been commented out. What **exactly** is the question you're asking here? We have no idea what "it's not working" means, and you do. (If you didn't, you wouldn't be posting here.) What **specifically** isn't working? What *actual problem* are you asking us to help you solve?

Comment: "It's not working" is not very informative; you should say what you expect and how it differs from what you get. As it is, your code has several errors and it doesn't call malloc. Please post code that matches the question, and v.v.

Comment: What do you want to attain here?

Comment: sorry for being unclear. What I wanted is this: for example, malloc allocates memory starting from the position 10000300 - 10000310. I want to write the string 'helloworld' into this segment of memory, starting from 1000030.

Comment: The reason for commenting out this line of code is because it did not work and I wanted to test the code below it.

Comment: Then post code that does that ... the code you posted does nothing of the sort.

Comment: @JimBalter, that's why I hoped to get some help here - I could not figure out the code. thanks

Comment: I've given several ways to code it in my answer. But again, you can't "figure out the code" if you write code to do something quite different from what you want to do -- the code you posted doesn't "write" (store) anything into memory. Note that you have two things you're interested in, the string "helloworld" and the memory you want to store it in. You won't be able to get there by calling both of them "charArray".

Comment: use `strcpy` or `strncpy` or `memcpy`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZECHAR 10

int main(void) {
        //create array for 10 characters plus null terminator
        char *charArray = malloc((SIZECHAR + 1) * sizeof(char));    

        //fill array with digits
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < SIZECHAR; i++) {
            charArray[i] = (char)('0' + i % 10);
        }
        //add null terminator to indicate the end of the string
        charArray[SIZECHAR] = '\0';

        //print the string, plus a newline
        printf("%s\n", charArray);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: a) You ought say what this does. b) Your array isn't NUL-terminated so the result of printing with %s is undefined behavior. c) You don't terminate the output with a newline. d) You don't address the errors in the OP's code, such as the bogus cast and printing an int rather than a pointer, contrary to the comment.

Comment: Better. You fill the array with '0' thru '9', not 0 through 10. Also, see my point (d).

Comment: Well this does something, but it's not clear to me what this has to do with the question.  Admittedly, I'm not sure what OP's question is.

Comment: @waTeim, I was a bit confused too. I took "write 10 char starting from the first position of malloc" and did that.

Comment: actually, I hoped to fill the array with the string "helloworld"  (length of 10 char)

Answer (score 1):

> sorry for being unclear. What I wanted is this: for example, malloc
>   allocates memory starting from the position 10000300 - 10000310. I
>   want to write the string 'helloworld' into this segment of memory,
>   starting from 1000030.

This does that (aside from your typo concerning the addresses):

```
char str[] = "helloworld";
char* mem = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
if (!mem) ReportOutOfMemoryAndExit();
strcpy(mem, str);
```

You can also use strdup instead of malloc and strcpy if you know the systems this code will run on support it.

To do this "manually", replace the strcopy call with

```
for (char *from = str, *to = mem; (*to++ = *from++) != 0;) { }
```

Some notes about the code you posted:

```
//      char *charArray = (char *)malloc(SIZECHAR * sizeof(char));
```

Don't cast the return value of malloc -- it isn't needed and it can hide bugs (namely, if the header that declares malloc isn't included). Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so that isn't needed. If you want to specify the size of the data type for generality, this is better written as

```
char* array = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof *array);
```

which will continue to work if you change the type of the array.

```
            int *currentIndex = (int *) charArray++;
```

There's no reason here to cast the pointer. Every cast is a "code smell" and you have two already. Also, a pointer isn't an index.

```
            printf("the current pointer is %i\n", *currentIndex);  // print out the current pointer
```

This doesn't print a pointer, it prints an `int` ... the `int` pointed to by your charArray cast to `int*`. This is undefined behavior because it isn't guaranteed that the char pointer can be treated as an int pointer ... on some architectures you'll get an alignment fault.

If you wanted to print the addresses where the chars are being stored,

```
    while (*charArray != '\0')
    {
            printf("the current pointer is %p\n", charArray++);  // print out the current pointer
    }
```

would do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZECHAR 10

int main(void){
    char *charArray = malloc((SIZECHAR+1) * sizeof(char));//+1 for terminator '\0',,
    char *p = strcpy(charArray, "helloworld");//write(copy) malloced addres;

    printf("top of address : %p\n", (void*)charArray);

    while (*p != '\0'){
        printf("the current pointer is %p(%c)\n", (void*)p, *p);
        ++p;
    }

    return 0;
}
```